# d3 append without nesting

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm wanting to create the following in d3:

```
<g>
    <rect class="rect1"></rect>
    <rect class="rect2"></rect>
</g>
```

Which I'm trying to do with:

```
rectangles
    .selectAll('g')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .append('rect')
    .addClass('rect1')
    .append('rect')
    .addClass('rect2')
```

However it's doing this:

```
<g>
    <rect class="rect1">
        <rect class="rect2"></rect>
    </rect>
</g>
```

How can I insert multiple rectangles per group at the same level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want something like this. You need to keep a reference to the g element so that you can create multiple children on it.

```
g = rectangles
    .selectAll('g')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('g')

g.append('rect')
    .addClass('rect1')

g.append('rect')
    .addClass('rect2')
```

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what i wanted!

Answer (score 0):

You can first add the `<g>` and then add one rectangle for each of the data, dynamically setting the class of each rectangle. For example:

```
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var rectangles = svg
    .append('g')
    .selectAll('rect')
    .data([0, 1])
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('class', function(d){ return 'rect' + (d+1); });
```